# best Practice for implementing Laravel Authentication class for Role based User Access

Tags: authentication, laravel

**Guys, I am trying to implement a solution for Role based access using Laravels Auth class**

I want to know what are the best practices for this, and to see where I am wrong in my implementation of the logic. Below is my code from the routes file. Please advise :)

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
if(Auth::user()){

    /* *****
        Inventory Clearence Roles 
        0 -> Inv Browser
        1 -> Inv Manager

    ******/

    $clearence =  Auth::user()->role;

    switch ($clearence){
        case 0:
            Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@role0task0'));
            Route::get('/task1', array('uses' => 'HomeController@role0task1'));
            Route::get('/task2', array('uses' => 'HomeController@role0task2'));
            break;
        case 1: 
            Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@role1task0'));
            Route::get('/taska1', array('uses' => 'HomeController@role1task1'));
            Route::get('/taska2', array('uses' => 'HomeController@role1task2'));
            break;
    }
}       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, creating conditionals routes in Laravel is not a very good practice. Before finding a route Laravel creates a list of all available routes and if your user is not authenticated all of those routes will simply disappear from the global list of routes. So if you do:

```
php artisan routes
```

You'll never see them, because in the command line there's never an authenticated user.

What me and others do in those cases is to check for authorization, in filters or even in your controller, after the hitting the route, and if the user has no rights to access that particular route, warn him about that and log the unauthorized access attempt.

This is an example using route filters for roles:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'browser', 'before' => 'role.browser'), function()
    {
        Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'BrowserController@index'));
        Route::get('task1', array('uses' => 'BrowserController@task1'));
        Route::get('task2', array('uses' => 'BrowserController@task2'));
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'manager', 'before' => 'role.manager'), function()
    {
        Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'ManagerController@index'));
        Route::get('task1', array('uses' => 'ManagerController@task1'));
        Route::get('task2', array('uses' => 'ManagerController@task2'));
    });
});
```

And the filters for each role:

```
Route::filter('role.browser', function()
{
    if (Auth::user()->role !== 0)
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'You are not authorized to view this page.');

        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
});

Route::filter('role.manager', function()
{
    if (Auth::user()->role !== 1)
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'You are not authorized to view this page.');

        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
});
```

Now if you do

```
php artisan routes
```

You should see all routes and which filters apply to them:

```
+--------+------------------------+-------+-------------------------+--------------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                    | Name  | Action                  | Before Filters     | After Filters |
+--------+------------------------+-------+-------------------------+--------------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD browser       |       | BrowserController@index | auth, role.browser |               |
|        | GET|HEAD browser/task1 |       | BrowserController@task1 | auth, role.browser |               |
|        | GET|HEAD browser/task2 |       | BrowserController@task2 | auth, role.browser |               |
|        | GET|HEAD manager       |       | ManagerController@index | auth, role.manager |               |
|        | GET|HEAD manager/task1 |       | ManagerController@task1 | auth, role.manager |               |
|        | GET|HEAD manager/task2 |       | ManagerController@task2 | auth, role.manager |               |
+--------+------------------------+-------+-------------------------+--------------------+---------------+
```